# Searching through a list of dictionaries using a condition to extract specifc elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a huge spreadsheet that I am attempting to search through for some specific data.

On the one hand I have IDs like this:

```
Y00988-11    
G01024-14    
Z01933-13
```

And on the other hand I have a massive spreadsheet(CSV) in the following format:

```
Run,Sample,Source,Rate,
DFT,G01024-14,A,High
DFT,U04424-15,B,Low
TFF,T64673-18,A,Low
RRT,I01324-14,A,High
RRT,J01624-14,A,High
...
```

I'm trying to extract both the '`Sample`' ID and the '`Run`' of IDs of interest.

I read the csv spreadsheet into a Dictionary using the in built reader, but I'm just having trouble extracting the elements I am interested in.

```
import csv
import sys

# IDs of interest
dataset=sys.argv[1]

# CSV spreadsheet
database=sys.argv[2]

sampleIDs=[]
with open(dataset, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line.strip('\n')
        sampleIDs.append(line)
file.close()

seq_Dict=[]
finalList=['init']


with open(database, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        seq_Dict.append(line)
csvfile.close()


for element in seq_Dict:
    for key, value in element.items():
        if element['Sample'] in sampleIDs:
            finalList.pop()
            finalList.append(element['Sample']+" "+element['Run'])

for i in finalList:
    print(i)
```

This script returns the info of the last ID in my sampleIDs, so I can see that what is occurring during the loop is being overwriting the previous iteration.
So I used `deepcopy` but that didn't work.

Comment: You're calling `key` and `value` for each item element but not using those variables at all. Did you want to check if one of those is in `sampleIDs` rather than `element['Sample']`?

Comment: Ah, yeah if an element in the list of  dictionaries contains the same ID then I want to extract the 'Sample' and 'Run' from its respective dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

With the new info that you provided me, here is why you get blocked.

```
for element in seq_Dict:
for key, value in element.items():
    if element['Sample'] in sampleIDs:
        finalList.pop()
        finalList.append(element['Sample']+" "+element['Run'])
```

Here `finalList.pop()` remove one object from your array than add one, that is why you see only the last one.

As well, this is useless because there is nothing into the loop `for element in seq_Dict:`. Use only the `for element in seq_Dict:` as you are not touching the `key` and `value`

```
for element in seq_Dict: 
for key, value in element.items():
    if element['Sample'] in sampleIDs:
```

Finally, here is the last version that I would suggest you.

```
for element in seq_Dict:
    if element['Sample'] in sampleIDs:
        finalList.append(sample +" "+element['Run'])
```

Comment: The sampleIDs are extracted from a list of IDs separated by new line characters.

Comment: There are 2 files. One contains the Sample IDs I want, the other contains all the sample IDs available as well as other information. I want to use the file containing the Sample IDs of interest to extract their corresponding 'Run' ID. But of course I would need to get the Sample ID as well for clarification. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for element in seq_Dict:
   sample = element['Sample']
   if sample in sampleIDs:
       finalList.append(sample +" "+element['Run'])
```